# Raspberry Pi Python SNMP library error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap

I develope raspberryi pi in SNMP trap message receiver.

I can not use libraries when doing this in raspberry  : [PYSNMP](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp)

Use this code in python file in terminal
I run this code

[Python Receive SNMP Trap Sample](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/twisted/manager/ntfrcv/v2c-multiple-interfaces.html)

This terminal error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/snmp $ python snmp_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snmp_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
  File "/home/pi/snmp/pysnmp/entity/engine.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pysnmp.proto.rfc3412 import MsgAndPduDispatcher
  File "/home/pi/snmp/pysnmp/proto/rfc3412.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pysnmp.proto.api import verdec  # XXX
  File "/home/pi/snmp/pysnmp/proto/api/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pysnmp.proto.api import v1, v2c, verdec
  File "/home/pi/snmp/pysnmp/proto/api/v2c.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pysnmp.proto import rfc1901, rfc1902, rfc1905
  File "/home/pi/snmp/pysnmp/proto/rfc1901.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pysnmp.proto import rfc1905
  File "/home/pi/snmp/pysnmp/proto/rfc1905.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pysnmp.proto import rfc1902
  File "/home/pi/snmp/pysnmp/proto/rfc1902.py", line 563, in <module>
    class Bits(OctetString):
  File "/home/pi/snmp/pysnmp/proto/rfc1902.py", line 614, in Bits
    def __init__(self, value=univ.noValue, tagSet=None, subtypeSpec=None,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'noValue'
```

Comment: Did you ran: `pip install pysnmp-apps`

Comment: Yes but not working :(

Comment: What result are you talking about?

Comment: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
 .....
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp_apps-0.4.1.dist-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log

Comment: That is an error. Are you getting this error after running: `pip install pysnmp-apps`?

Comment: Yes :( I get this error when I run the command -> pip install pysnmp-apps

Comment: You get which error?

Comment: perhaps you should be typing: sudo pip install pysnmp-apps

Comment: hi barny sudo pip install pysnmp-apps is working now but Now i am getting this error :  pi@raspberrypi:~/snmp $ python snmp_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snmp_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pysnmp.carrier.twisted import dispatch
  File "/home/pi/snmp/pysnmp/carrier/twisted/dispatch.py", line 16, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, task
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet

Comment: this error solution :  apt-get install python-twisted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed according to @barny's suggestion. Problem solved:

```
sudo pip install pysnmp-apps
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely a package dependency problem. What you need is to install pysnmp:

```
pip install pysnmp
```

What will also install the required dependencies. From the traceback it looks like you have an older pyasn1 (which is the dependency) compared to the version pysnmp is expected.

Comment: When I write this (pip install pysnmp) to the terminal I get the following error.  But when I write (sudo pip install pysnmp-apps) this the installation was successful.